# Realm saving in Android (RealmList<RealmString>): Values get saved to RealmString model twice

Tags: android, realm

I need some help with Realm.
I have a Realm object: `PokemonExperience` with `RealmList<RealmString>`

```
public class PokemonExperience extends RealmObject {

    public RealmList<RealmString> mainSkills;

    public RealmList<RealmString> getMainSkills() {
        return mainSkills;
    }

    public void setMainSkills(RealmList<RealmString> mainSkills) {
        this.mainSkills = mainSkills;
    }
```

And I have my `RealmString` object as well, with only value field.

With this, I have a multiple choice list with checkboxes, and these checkboxes have onClickListeners. When I check the boxes, I would like to save all the values into my `RealmString` model, and then save the RealmStrings into the `RealmList<RealmString>` in my `PokemonExperience` model.

Here's my code to do that:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        //inflate Layout
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_multiple_choice_adapter, parent, false);
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_multiple_choice_checkbox);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            setCheckListener(viewHolder);
        });
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    if (selectedPositions.size() == 0) {
        Method getter = getGetter(field);
        try {           
            List<Object> values = Arrays.asList(data.values().toArray());
            Object result = getter.invoke(object);
            List<Object> resultAsList = (List<Object>) result;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                 if (resultAsList.contains(values.get(i))) {
                      selectedPositions.add(i);
                 }
                viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(position == selectedPositions.get(i));
                viewHolder.position = position;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    List<Object> keys = Arrays.asList(data.keySet().toArray());
    viewHolder.textView.setText(keys.get(position).toString());
    viewHolder.position = position;
    return convertView;
}

private Method getSetter(Field field) {
    return settersMap.get(field);
}

private Method getGetter(Field field) {
    return gettersMap.get(field);
}

private boolean isGetter(Method method) {
    return method.getName().startsWith("get") &&
            method.getParameterTypes().length == 0 &&
            !void.class.equals(method.getReturnType());
}

private boolean isSetter(Method method) {
    return method.getName().startsWith("set") &&
            method.getParameterTypes().length == 1;
}

private String croppedMethodName(boolean isGetter, boolean isSetter, Method method) {
    if (!isGetter && !isSetter) {
        return null;
    }

    if (isSetter &&
            method.getParameterTypes()[0].getName().equals(boolean.class.getCanonicalName())) {

        char[] c = new StringBuilder(method.getName()).substring(2).toCharArray();
        c[0] = Character.toLowerCase(c[0]);
        return new String(c);
    }

    char[] c = new StringBuilder(method.getName()).substring(3).toCharArray();
    c[0] = Character.toLowerCase(c[0]);
    return new String(c);
}

private void setCheckListener(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    selectedPosition = viewHolder.position;
    Log.d(TAG, "getView: 111: " + selectedPosition);
    // We save our values here to Realm
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    Method setter = getSetter(field);
    try {
        List<Object> values = Arrays.asList(data.values().toArray());
        // taking a piece of string based on viewHolder.position to determine
        // what is the "object" we should be saving
        Object selectedObject = values.get(viewHolder.position);
        Log.d(TAG, "selectedObject: " + selectedObject);
        RealmString selectedRealmString = (RealmString) selectedObject;
        Log.d(TAG, "realmString: " + selectedRealmString);
        String selectedRealmStringValue = selectedRealmString.getValue();
        Log.d(TAG, "realmStringValue: " + selectedRealmStringValue);
        RealmResults<RealmString> realmStrings = realm.where(RealmString.class).findAll();
        if (!realmStrings.contains(selectedRealmStringValue)) {
            selectedRealmString = new RealmString();
            selectedRealmString.setValue(selectedRealmStringValue);
            realm.copyToRealm(selectedRealmString);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "saved realmString: " + selectedRealmString);
        Log.d(TAG, "saved realmStringValue: " + selectedRealmStringValue);
        Log.d(TAG, "RealmResult size: " + realmStrings.size());
        Log.d(TAG, "RealmResult: " + realmStrings.toArray().toString());
        Method getter = getGetter(field);
        Log.d(TAG, "getter name: " + getter.getName());
        Object existingObjects = getter.invoke(object);
        Log.d(TAG, "existingObjects: " + existingObjects);
        RealmList<RealmString> existingValues;
        existingValues = (RealmList<RealmString>) existingObjects;
        Log.d(TAG, "existingValues1: " + existingValues);
        if (!existingValues.contains(selectedRealmString)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "existingValues2: " + existingValues);
            existingValues.add(selectedRealmString);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "existingValues3: " + existingValues);
        setter.invoke(object, existingValues);
        Log.d(TAG, "setCheckListener: setter is: " + setter.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close();
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My questions:

1. Why are my values saved to My RealmString model twice? Whenever I click on any checkbox, the String value of that checkbox gets saved twice.
2. Why are the values saved to the RealmString model even though there is a check for that.

   if (!realmStrings.contains(selectedRealmStringValue)) {
      //...
   }

This is supposed to ensure that only new values are saved.

3. The `RealmList<RealmString>` does not get saved to my PokemonExperience's mainSkills field.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: when you click at checkbox.  `Log.d(TAG, "getView: 111: " + selectedPosition);`  called one or twice

Comment: Hi Phan, it gets called only once

Comment: using `RealmString` is a bad way of handling primitive lists.

Comment: There's another good solution to this if you want: https://hackernoon.com/realmlist-realmstring-is-an-anti-pattern-bfc10efb7ca5#.s4ws0xdw8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedRealmString` is an unmanaged object, and you are inserting into your Realm twice (`realm.copyToRealm(selectedRealmString)` and `existingValues.add(selectedRealmString)`). You could do `selectedRealmStringManaged = realm.copyToRealm(selectedRealmString)` and later do `existingValues.add(selectedRealmStringManaged)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check like that

```
if (!realmStrings.contains(selectedRealmString)) {
   ...    
}
```

because `selectedRealmString` is instance of `RealmString` class, `selectedRealmStringValue` is instance of `String` class and your `RealmResults` contains `RealmString`

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have tried that as well, but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!realmStrings.contains(selectedRealmString)) {
   ...    
}
```

The above doesn't work because what we really need to do is to compare the value of the objects.
This works:

```
        ArrayList<String> existingValuesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < existingValues.size(); i++) {
            existingValuesArrayList.add(existingValues.get(i).getValue());
        }
        if (!existingValuesArrayList.contains(selectedRealmString.getValue())) {
        //...
        }
```